# How to prevent save from a behavior in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I want to add a check before save in several of my Yii2 models.

In Yii1 this was simply a case of adding a behavior that had a beforeSave method, that returned false.

This doesn't work in Yii2. I can register a behavior that is called before save, but returning false from it doesn't prevent that save.

Anyone know how to achieve this without having to duplicate a beforeSave method with identical code in all my models?

```
namespace app\components\behaviors;

use yii\base\Behavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class PreventSaveBehavior extends Behavior
{

    public function events()
    {
        return [
            ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => 'beforeSave',
            ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'beforeSave',
        ];
    }

    public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if (SomeClass::shouldWePreventSave()) {
            return false;
        }

        return parent::beforeSave($insert);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Yii2 in behaviors you need to use [`isValid`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-modelevent#$isValid-detail) property of `ModelEvent`.

```
public function beforeSave($event)
{
    if (SomeClass::shouldWePreventSave()) {
        $event->isValid = false;
    }
}
```

This is explained in [event documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT-detail).

Comment: Ah lovely, thanks. This is quite a change from Yii1, and I was still trying to use "beforeSave" in the same way, as other examples had shown it.